# How to normalize uneven JSON structures in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using the Google Maps Distance Matrix API to get several distances from multiple origins. The API response comes in a JSON structured like:

```json
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "Destination 1",
        "Destination 2",
        "Destination 3"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "Origin 1",
        "Origin 2"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "8.7 km",
                        "value": 8687
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "19 mins",
                        "value": 1129
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "223 km",
                        "value": 222709
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "2 hours 42 mins",
                        "value": 9704
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "299 km",
                        "value": 299156
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "4 hours 17 mins",
                        "value": 15400
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "216 km",
                        "value": 215788
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "2 hours 44 mins",
                        "value": 9851
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "20.3 km",
                        "value": 20285
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "21 mins",
                        "value": 1283
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "210 km",
                        "value": 210299
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "2 hours 45 mins",
                        "value": 9879
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Note the **rows** array has the same number of elements in *origin_addresses* (2), while each **elements** array has the same number of elements in *destination_addresses* (3).

Is one able to use the pandas API to normalize everything inside **rows** while fetching the corresponding data from *origin_addresses* and *destination_addresses*?

The output should be:

```py
  status distance.text  distance.value    duration.text  duration.value origin_addresses destination_addresses
0     OK        8.7 km            8687          19 mins            1129         Origin 1         Destination 1
1     OK        223 km          222709  2 hours 42 mins            9704         Origin 1         Destination 2
2     OK        299 km          299156  4 hours 17 mins           15400         Origin 1         Destination 3
3     OK        216 km          215788  2 hours 44 mins            9851         Origin 2         Destination 1
4     OK       20.3 km           20285          21 mins            1283         Origin 2         Destination 2
5     OK        210 km          210299  2 hours 45 mins            9879         Origin 2         Destination 3
```

If pandas does not provide a relatively simple way to do it, how would one accomplish this operation?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` contains the dictionary from the question you can try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data["rows"])
df["origin_addresses"] = data["origin_addresses"]
df = df.explode("elements")

df = pd.concat([df.pop("elements").apply(pd.Series), df], axis=1)

df = pd.concat(
    [df.pop("distance").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("distance."), df], axis=1
)

df = pd.concat(
    [df.pop("duration").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("duration."), df], axis=1
)

df["destination_addresses"] = data["destination_addresses"] * len(
    data["origin_addresses"]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     duration.text  duration.value distance.text  distance.value status origin_addresses destination_addresses
0          19 mins            1129        8.7 km            8687     OK         Origin 1         Destination 1
0  2 hours 42 mins            9704        223 km          222709     OK         Origin 1         Destination 2
0  4 hours 17 mins           15400        299 km          299156     OK         Origin 1         Destination 3
1  2 hours 44 mins            9851        216 km          215788     OK         Origin 2         Destination 1
1          21 mins            1283       20.3 km           20285     OK         Origin 2         Destination 2
1  2 hours 45 mins            9879        210 km          210299     OK         Origin 2         Destination 3
```